# Ndk Android Studio Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

i am trying to integrate ndk project in my app.it is fine in eclipse.in Android Studio its giving error..

```
   C:\Android\sample\app\src\main\jni\libogg\bitwise.c:24:21: fatal error: 
  ogg/ogg.h: No such file or directory #include <ogg/ogg.h>                     ^
 compilation terminated.make.exe: ***        [C:\Android\sample\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/app/C_\Android\sample\app\src\main\jni\libogg\bitwise.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You are probably looking for *[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27840210/192373)*. TL;NR Android Studio by default ignores your **Android.mk**, you need special trick to force it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Android Studio 1.3 at Canary channel which supports NDK fully. Reference: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Comment: NDK is *now* (Jul 10) supported in Android Studio 1.3 RC1. Prior it was only shown at Google IO. https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/canary/latest