# How to prevent the auto generation of Android.mk with new gradle experimental Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm trying build NDK project with new Gradle experimental plugin, but it seems that Gradle ignores the Android.mk and starts to compile everything without paying an attention to what written in the Android.mk, I am aware of the new syntax and I read the following [Experimental Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) also I tried the following syntax:

```
    android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs = []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it still ignoring the Android.mk file.
I'm using:

- Android Studio 1.3.1 stable
- Gradle 2.5 with experimental plugin 0.2.0

Can anyone advise to that?

Comment: A search found several StackOverflow questions that seemed related to this, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833530/how-to-use-my-own-android-mk-file-with-android-sudio

Comment: searched the whole StackOverflow , please pay attention that I'm using the new gradle experimental plugin that has different syntax and works different than the standard gradle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you set

```
android.sources{
    main.jni {
        source {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/none'] // [] could be set instead but will disable even symbol resolution inside the editor
        }
    }
    main.jniLibs {
        source {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
        }
    }
}
```

Android Studio will not try to build your sources, and it will integrate your .so files that are inside `src/main/libs/<abi>/`

That means you can call `ndk-build` yourself, and your Makefiles will not be ignored.

Comment: This works, but there's some typos:
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/none']

                    srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']

Comment: Any chance you have advice on a similar jni.source question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285107/gradle-experimental-includes

Answer (score 0):

Try to put:

```
 android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Inside your `gradle.properties` file.

Then, you should be able to use the syntax you mention in your question.

Comment: that will work but i'm trying to use experimental plugin to get ndk debugging ability.

Comment: I think they drop the support of the Android.mk file with the new experimental plugin. You have to use gradle's build.gradle. I will be glade if someone could prove me wrong on this!