# Gradle-experimental includes

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

What is the build.gradle equivalent of:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libcharset \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libcharset/include/ \
```

that would be found in Android.mk.

I've tried various forms of `jni.source.srcDirs`

The documentation defines:

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "native"
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDir 'src'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the equivalent does not find the includes:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs += '/src/main/jni/libiconv'
                srcDirs += "/src/main/jni/libiconv/include"
                srcDirs += "/src/main/jni/libiconv/lib"
                srcDirs += "/src/main/jni/libiconv/libcharset"
                srcDirs += "/src/main/jni/libiconv/libcharset/include"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs = ["/src/main/jni/libiconv",
                           "/src/main/jni/libiconv/include",
                           "/src/main/jni/libiconv/lib",
                           "/src/main/jni/libiconv/libcharset",
                           "/src/main/jni/libiconv/libcharset/include" ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the JNI plugin (which I have never used) is anything like the Java plugins, the `srcDirs` property is a collection, and you can allocate it like `[ 'dir1', 'dir2' ]` and/or use the `+=` operator to add elements. Not posting as an aswer, because it could well be you already know this.

Comment: Yah, we're on the same page.  My initial error was a sneaky stray brace as I uncommented build.gradle sections I'd converted for testing.  However, I'm still not having luck so far adding the includes.

Answer (score 1):

srcDirs is used to specify sources only. The DSL doesn't support yet a way to specify includes directly, but you can use cppFlags for this:

```
android.ndk {
    //...
    cppFlags  += "-I${file("src/main/jni/libiconv/include")}".toString()
    //...
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I thought the includes were the source directories.

Comment: The includes are the paths to your *.h* files and the sources are all your *.c*/*.cpp* files. You don't need to add include paths if your .h are referenced relatively from each of your source files, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: What if I want to use `CFlags`, is it the same as `cppFlags`?