# How to include third-party *.a into Android NDK using android studio.?

Tags: android-ndk, android-studio-import

I am having .a file from third-party. How can use it in android studio?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use directly a `.a` library in your app. This libraries are static and Android app only allow you to load dynamic libraries.

But you can build a dynamic library linking with your static library. Si you just have to add a few line to you Android.mk to link with this static library. Put your prebuilt `.a` and his header in a prebuild jni alongside your jni folder. Then your Android.mk should look like something like this :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := YourStaticLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuilt/your_static_lib_prebuild.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../prebuilt
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := DynamicLib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
                $(LOCAL_PATH)/../prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := your_src_file.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
LOCAL_ARM_NEON  := true

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := YourStaticLib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response. Here I have small doubt. How to add Android.mk file inside android studio?

Comment: You are welcome. What did you use to build your native code ?

Comment: Am using "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0". Is that any other way to build without Android.mk. Is there is no other ways then pls guide me how to override ndk_build in build.gradle file...

Comment: I don't know how to do this, using only gradle. But you can make gradle using your own Android.mk file. This answer on SO explain how to http://stackoverflow.com/a/27840210/4170584