# What is the name of scripts in Android.mk file and how to say Android Studio colorize the text inside?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

What is the name of script/language written in Android.mk and application.mk files?
My Android Studio does not recognize it and shows it as a text file. Is it possible to make it easier to read and add autocomplete capability?

Comment: Android studio by default uses gradle to regenerate android.mk scripts to compile ndk modules. About .mk files, I think that it is a specific language for android architectures very similar to c++ linux/unix makefiles. It is possible to use your own android.mk as the first answer of your question. But I think that there is no any highlighting plugin for  android studio to recognize the .mk files.

Answer (score -1):

Please, follow the official documentation guide: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html

By the Way, as far as I can go, there's not a ready to use edit tool with auto completion and such but there's enough documentation and references online:

[How to use my own Android.mk file with Android Sudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833530/how-to-use-my-own-android-mk-file-with-android-sudio)

http://android.mk/

Comment: any comments on why the negative voting?

Comment: I asked `What is the name?` You just referred to a link to follow the instructions! I didn't need the instructions. Again I asked a way to colorize and speedup codding, but you redirected me to a documentation that every one can see them in the first google search. Please read the questions more carefully. There is no need to answer a question you don't know the answer. It was better to comment not answer. Answering a question really decrease the visit rate.