# Android studio issues with linking gradle to android mk file

Tags: android-studio

I am trying add a .so files to a dlib libary in android studio. I have followed the following steps

Migrate from ndkCompile
If you're using the deprecated ndkCompile, you should migrate to using either CMake or ndk-build. Because ndkCompile generates an intermediate Android.mk file for you, migrating to ndk-build may be a simpler choice.

To migrate from ndkCompile to ndk-build, proceed as follows:

Compile your project with ndkCompile at least once by selecting Build > Make Project. This generates the Android.mk file for you.
Locate the auto-generated Android.mk file by navigating to project-root/module-root/build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk.
Relocate the Android.mk file to some other directory, such as the same directory as your module-level build.gradle file. This makes sure that Gradle doesn't delete the script file when running the clean task.
Open the Android.mk file and edit any paths in the script such that they are relative to the current location of the script file.
Link Gradle to the Android.mk file .
Disable ndkCompile by opening the build.properties file and removing the following line:
// Remove this line
android.useDeprecatedNdk = true
Apply your changes by clicking Sync Project   in the toolbar.

However I am getting this error saying the project cant configure.

org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':dlib'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(Li

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: [see this if it can help you , I have the same problem still figuring out what i should do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27840210/10670947)

Comment: [by default the gradle android plugin regenerates and uses its own Android.mk file to compile your sources.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27840210/10670947)