# Undefined reference to isfinite

Tags: android, c

I had following error when done cross compilation for android.

```
Cross compiler used SDK/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi' 
./libgpsd.a(libgpsd_core.o):libgpsd_core.c:function gpsd_poll: error: undefined reference to '__isfinite'
./libgpsd.a(libgpsd_core.o):libgpsd_core.c:function gpsd_poll: error: undefined reference to '__isfinite'
./libgpsd.a(libgpsd_core.o):libgpsd_core.c:function gpsd_poll: error: undefined reference to '__isfinite'
./libgpsd.a(libgpsd_core.o):libgpsd_core.c:function gpsd_poll: error: undefined reference to '__isfinite'
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `infinite()` is part of C99. Add `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99` to your Android.mk. See question [How to set standard c99 for compile android NDK project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484795/how-to-set-standard-c99-for-compile-android-ndk-project)

Comment: Also note that there is an offending flag `-ansi` that will cause the error.