# Loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk

I have problem with building my android project with c++ file. It says that I must compile with C++11:

```
error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
```

And I know what this means, but I want to use c++11. And I have it included in gradle config:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "native"

    stl = "gnustl_static"
    cppFlags += "-std=c++11"
    cppFlags += "-fexceptions"
    ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log', 'OpenSLES'])
}
```

For what I searched, everyone has it same and it works. Does anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it must be

```
CFlags.add("-std=c11")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've already had a loop like this:

```
for(int i = low; i <= high; ++i)
        {
                res = runalg(i);
                if (res > highestres)
                {
                        highestres = res;
                }

        }
```

Please, declare var `i` outside of the loop.

It should solve the problem.

Think also about using `while` instead of `for` if possible.

EDIT: I found a solution which may be interesting for you:

> In your Android.mk add
>
> ```
> LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_ndktest_TestLib.c
> LOCAL_MODULE := com_example_ndktest_TestLib
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```
>
> Make sure you add 'LOCAL_CFLAGS' after adding 'include $(CLEAR_VARS)'

From: [How to set standard c99 for compile android NDK project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484795/how-to-set-standard-c99-for-compile-android-ndk-project)

Please check also link above.

Hope it help